# How to express $or when using cl-mongo

Tags: mongodb, lisp, common-lisp

I read the whole docs at https://github.com/fons/cl-mongo and understand `(db.find "foo" (kv ($> "i" 3) ($< "j" 5)))` means query when "i>3 **AND** j<5".
My question is what's the code for "$or"? like query when i>3 **or** j<5?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to translate whatever you need to express in mongo's format using the primitives of cl-mongo.

In mongo, I think that it would be:

```
{$or: [{i: {$gt: 3}},
       {j: {$lt: 5}}]}
```

In cl-mongo, you translate "object"s to `kv` forms, and "array"s to lists.  Many mongo operators have shorthands defined, but I think `$or` is not one of them, so you'd need to either define that or do it explicitly:

```
(kv "$or"
    (list ($> i 3)
          ($< j 5)))
```

A convenience macro for `$or` might look like this:

```
(defmacro $or (&rest forms)
  `(kv "$or" (list ,@forms)))
```

Then you can write

```
($or ($> i 3)
     ($< j 5))
```

(untested).